# How do I use HTML and CSS in an EXE

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to program with HTML and CSS and have it render in the form of a Windows application.

What is the best way to do this, so I don't have to get my hands too dirty using C++?

EDIT: I see seamonkey is very confused about what im asking, so ill explain. I want to program in HTML/CSS and use that program as an offline application instead of a webpage. Ive heard useful tips like including IE9's html renderer in my program and also using HTA files or even using Chrome apps. Im still open to other suggestions.

Comment: you could use nw.js or electron to set up a project easily http://tangiblejs.com/posts/nw-js-electron-compared

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. I've interpreted it as: 'I want to make a web application but make it look like a standard desktop application.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, you (in essesnce) embed the Internet Explorer viewer into your application.  I have done it before and it is pretty easy.  To do that, just create an MFC application then use the MFC  [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752041(v=vs.85).aspx)  Control

Here is an article on how to do that.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752046(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That's not what the question asks.

Comment: @cyber That is the way I read his question.  "I'm looking for a way to program with HTML and CSS and have it render in the form of an offline windows application.  This will allow him to write is HTML and CSS and have those display in a windows application.  Maybe you should let the author decide what he is asking.

Comment: This question asks about programming a web-application & have it *render* as a standard desktop application.

Comment: Your interpretation, he doesn't say "web-application" anywhere in his question.  He just said he wants to write a Windows Application that can display HTML and CSS offline.

Comment: `html and css ... have it render in the form of an offline windows application.` - they want to make a website that is styled in the form of a Windows application. No-where in the question does the OP state that they want to write a Windows application, and I'm guessing that the [tag:c++] & [tag:exe] tags are there for attention.

Comment: Actually, this guy is on point. Thanks for the help, ill be sure to use this info in the future